# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range VBA Excel 2003

Tags: vba, excel

I am newbie in VBA, currently, I am trying to refresh my data from Excel, and it hit `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range` in Excel 2003 but works well in Excel 2010.

it hit in line:

```
Sheets("Tape and Reel").ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh
```

Would need help from all. Appreciate your reply

Comment: Double check that the sheet name is spelled correctly and that there are not extra spaces or other non printable items.

Comment: It could also be good if you just copy and paste the sheet name to your vba code.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for your reply, yes i did, and it works well in Excel 2010, only hit the error in Excel 2003, unsure if ListObject could be call in Excel 2003.

Comment: @ramedju Thank you for your reply, yes i copy and paste the sheet name directly as well.

Comment: Start by separating the different calls out so you can see which one fails. If the reference to `Sheets` is wrong, then `ListObjects` will fail. If `ListObjects(1)` doesn't have a `QueryTable`, it will fail. Figure out which one isn't working. Then use the debugger to find out why it's failing. We can't do that for you.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your reply. i tried MsgBox Sheets("Tape and Reel").QueryTables.Count and it show 0 QueryTable which it hit what you try to explain. Wonder why it can be execute in Excel 2010 without hit any error but not in Excel 2003

Comment: can you rename your sheet to `test` without spaces? And also try : `Sheets("test").ListObjects(1).Refresh`  or `Sheets("Tape and Reel").ListObjects(0).QueryTable.Refresh`

Comment: @ramedju still hit the same error for both

Comment: AHhh, what data are you referring and and in what form is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it out so that you can see exactly where your issue is.

Example:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet, QT As QueryTable

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tape And Reel")
Set QT = WS.ListObjects(1).QueryTable
QT.Refresh
```

**EDIT**
Since you found it in the second line, you could try to loop through the workbook and find it. Here is an idea:

```
Dim ob As ListObject

For Each ob In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tape And Reel").ListObjects
    Debug.Print ob.Name
Next ob
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
it hit error in the line 
Set QT = WS.ListObjects(1).QueryTable
It looks like in Excel 2003 could not find the querytable, in Excel 2010 the querytable is actually being added as ListObject.

Comment: It will prompt the listobject name in Excel 2010 as "Tables_query_From_DetailsDTL" but if execute in Excel 2003, there will be nothing print/return..

Comment: Uh... are you sure it's there?

Comment: yea :(
been cracking my head over hours for this issue... have no idea where to dig more....

Comment: i think i got it, i try to recreate it in Excel 2003, same steps how i create in Excel 2010, it solve the error...looks like the query create in Excel 2010 is listobject but in Excel 2003 is create as querytable. so it return nothing when try to loop it. Thanks alot

Comment: @lazybug you're not even going to accept the answer that get you there, or at least mark it as "useful"? Uh... you're welcome.